# MySQL triggers cannot update rows in same table the trigger is assigned to. Suggested workaround?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, stored-procedures, triggers

MySQL doesn't currently support updating rows in the same table the trigger is assigned to since the call could become recursive. Does anyone have suggestions on a good workaround/alternative? Right now my plan is to call a stored procedure that performs the logic I really wanted in a trigger, but I'd love to hear how others have gotten around this limitation.

Edit: A little more background as requested. I have a table that stores product attribute assignments. When a new parent product record is inserted, I'd like the trigger to perform a corresponding insert in the same table for each child record. This denormalization is necessary for performance. MySQL doesn't support this and throws:

`Can't update table 'mytable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`  A long discussion on the issue on [the MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,122354,122354) basically lead to: Use a stored proc, which is what I went with for now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add some more details to your question. What are you trying to accomplish in these updates?

Comment: Are you trying to update rows other than the ones that the insert update or delete contained?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this ? - I also need to update multiple rows in the same table when one of the rows with a unique field is updated ?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually up the rows in the same table as the trigger. The thread you linked to even has the solution.

**For example:**

```
TestTable ( id / lastmodified / random )

create trigger insert_lastmod
before insert on TestTable
for each row
set NEW.lastmodified = NOW();

insert into TestTable ( `random` ) values ( 'Random' );

select * from TestTable;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | lastmodified        | random              |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2010-12-22 14:15:23 | Random              |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I needed to update or insert multiple rows in the same table when the trigger runs. Unless I'm mistaken this still isn't supported.

Comment: The example above updates the same table when the insert trigger fires.

Comment: You're manipulating only the rows just inserted. This question is about manipulating other existing rows in the table when a given row is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could call the stored proc in your trigger.  HOwever, if you want to update some fields in the same records that you are changing (such as an updatedby  or lastupdated column) then you can do this in a beofre trigger according to the refernce manual. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

This is a common operation for triggers and I find it difficult to believe it isn't supported.

Comment: Undestood. Sadly, I need to update or insert multiple rows in the same table when the trigger runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update column that you don't *read* in trigger function, then as a workaround, you could put that column into separate table.

Answer (score -2):

You can actually do that
The below is an example for same

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger test2 
before insert on ptrt 
for each row 
begin 
if NEW.DType = "A" then 
set NEW.PA = 500; 

elseif NEW.DType = "B" then 
set NEW.PA = 1000; 

else 
set NEW.PA = 0; 
END IF; 
END;$$

DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me :D

On Before / Update.

```
BEGIN
 SET NEW.DateTimeUpdated = NOW();
END
```

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple values on the same column as the question wanted.