# MySQL procedure to delete related rows

Tags: mysql, procedure, delete-row

I've got table:

```
id  parent  name
```

Now, the parent field is the id of other row.
I cannot use trigger for that as MySQL says:

> Can't update table 'products_categories' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

How a procedure should look like to delete all rows that has parent like deleted id?

Comment: do you need only children, or all descendents?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334478/mysql-triggers-cannot-update-rows-in-same-table-the-trigger-is-assigned-to-sugg

Comment: @srini.venigalla Let's say I delete id=40. Then trigger/procedure should delete all rows with parent=40. When it removes all the others, the trigger/procedure should work too for them.

Comment: @rzeka your model is called Adjacency model. Traversing a hierarchy in Adjacency models require the underlying db to support some sort of recursion, which mysql does not support. You would be better served by Nested models. Traversing nested models do not require recursion. Please Google for "Celko Nested Model delete rows" you will get plenty of literature. There is also a procedure to create a nested model from Adjaceny Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the procedure recursively. The procedure must do the following:

- Read `parent` value into variable
- Remove the record (by its `id`)
- If `parent` value is not NULL - call the procedure again and pass `parent` value as IN argument.

Check server variable **max_sp_recursion_depth** - the number of times that a stored procedure may call itself.