# mysql delete then update

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way/approach in MySQL wherein if I drop a certain row, the next row(s) will probably be updated? To illustrate what I mean, say for example I have here a table:

```
+--------------+
|  id  | order |
+--------------+
|  115 |     1 |
|  116 |     2 |
|  117 |     3 |
|  118 |     1 |
|  119 |     2 |
|  120 |     6 |
|  121 |     7 |
|  122 |     8 |
+--------------+
```

I'm about to drop `id = 117`, if the action is success I want `id = 118` to have its order to 3 from 1 which is the current order of dropped `id = 117`. Then make `id = 119` to have order 4, then `id = 120` to 5, and so on.

I'm doing this because I have some sort of ordering rows in my PHP program.

Comment: Have you looked at a delete trigger?

Comment: Did You solve the problem?, it what case do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you will have to repopulate the order column completely because if you delete row id 118 or 119, you need to change 118,119,120 and so on till the end of table

```
 update order1,(select @rownum:=0)dummy set order1 = 
(@rownum =@rownum+1);
```

so in this case if you delete 118

```
Delete from YourTable where id = 118
```

run the above update script, it works

Comment: What does @rownum:=0 means? Can you explain the script a little? Thanks.

Comment: @rownum =0 will set intial value for rownum vairable, then it gets updated to +1 after updating each row, you can also use order by id for correct ordering

Answer (score 0):

You need to have MySQL 5+. From MySQL 5 onwards we have triggers. Triggers are programs that fire or are executed when an insert , update or delete action occurs on a specific table. So you can create a "`BEFORE`" "`DELETE`" trigger where you can open a `cursor` on the same table that  will select rows with IDs after the `OLD.id` where `OLD` means the deleted rows data table (called magic tables). Then it is a case of simply issuing the required `UPDATE` command to update the relevant rows in it.

You can refer to the deleted rows data as `OLD.col_name`. In an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` trigger you can also access `NEW.col_name` to refer to the inserted data. Only in the `UPDATE` trigger you can access both the `NEW` and `OLD` magic tables.

Links: 
[MySQL triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)
[Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)

Comment: Possibly, but still I need to execute `UPDATE` within the trigger, which quite confuse me.

Comment: Even if you do the code in PHP you will have to code an UPDATE in any case. And a PHP programmer cant afford to be confused by UPDATE. You can look at a nice training material on SQL's UPDATE here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: you cannot execute an update on the same table in trigger it will give error

Comment: @NaveenKumar probably, any ideas?

Comment: If size of table is not that large use a temporary table, update that table in the trigger

Comment: Can u try Before Delete trigger instead of After delete? As per this thread it works fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334478/mysql-triggers-cannot-update-rows-in-same-table-the-trigger-is-assigned-to-sugg