# Trigger - Error #1442 Can't update [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers, mysql-error-1442

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL triggers cannot update rows in same table the trigger is assigned to. Suggested workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334478/mysql-triggers-cannot-update-rows-in-same-table-the-trigger-is-assigned-to-sugg)

I have some problems with this trigger:

```
create trigger pay_out before insert on `payment_out`
for each row
then
UPDATE `payment_out` o
INNER JOIN payment p ON p.id_1 = o.id_1 AND o.id2 = p.id2
SET o.`how_much_to_pay` = p.cash / p.months;
end;
$$
```

```
table payment_out
id1
id2
how_much_to_pay

table payment
id1
id2
cash
months
```

ERROR:

> 1442 - Can't update table payment_out in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

When I make something like "new.o.how_much_to_pay" it says it doesn't see column named new.o.how_much_to_pay. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be triggered AFTER insert though?

Comment: It  doesn't change a thing, so it's not that.