# Can't update table in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I made new trigger, which has to update the salary of employee. It takes 2 values (cash, and months) from table payment, and divides them into a column "how_much_to_pay".

I looked at topic:
[MySQL triggers cannot update rows in same table the trigger is assigned to. Suggested workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334478/mysql-triggers-cannot-update-rows-in-same-table-the-trigger-is-assigned-to-sugg)

But it didin't help me since they use only from 1 table and they can put "new" without a problem.

Here is my trigger:

```
create trigger pay_out before insert on `payment_out`
for each row
then
UPDATE `payment_out` o
INNER JOIN payment p ON p.id_1 = o.id_1 AND o.id2 = p.id2
SET o.`how_much_to_pay` = p.cash / p.months;
end;
$$
```

Here are tables:

```
table payment_out
id1
id2
how_much_to_pay

table payment
id1
id2
cash
months
```

And the error itself:

```
1442 - Can't update table payment_out in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one-to-one relation between two tables, then you can use this code in BEFORE INSERT trigger -

```
BEGIN
  SELECT p.cash, p.months INTO @cash, @months
    FROM payment p
    WHERE p.id_1 = NEW.id_1 AND p.id2 = NEW.id2;

  SET NEW.how_much_to_pay = @cash / @months;
END
```

Comment: Well, this works but the "how much to pay" is NULL, even tho cash = 8000, and months = 8.

Comment: It can be null if one of `p.cash` or `p.months` is NULL. Try to run SELECT from the trigger, add correct values to WHERE condition. What is the result?

Comment: When I noticed it, I changed it to 0.00.